# AnyLogic: Internal error while building model

Tags: anylogic

I'm attempting to build a new model in AnyLogic and I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I'm really grasping at straws to identify what is going wrong as there are no errors in the Problem window. The only thing I can think of is that a while ago I copy-pasted Agents and classes from old models into this one. However, the model compiled and ran after the copy-paste, so if related then this is a very delayed bug. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: it was a problem with AnyLogic's `RunConfiguration`. To fix it I did the following:

1. I checked `ignore` on all of my agents and classes.
2. I tried to build the model; as expected, `RunConfiguration` fails to build as it no longer has a top-level agent.
3. I unchecked `ignore` on all of my agents and classes and gave `RunConfiguration` a new top-level agent.
4. Internally, this changes the `RunConfiguration`'s `ActiveObjectClassId`, which, for whatever reason, resolves the problem.

Hopefully this helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

As @Dylan Knowles suggested, I encountered a problem with `Run Configuration`. Although his solution did not work for me, I was able to resolve the issue by following these steps:

1. I deleted the agent Main.
2. I recreated the agent Main.
3. I set the `top-level agent` in `Run Configuration` to Main.

After completing these steps, the problem was fixed. I believe that I may have accidentally edited or deleted the top-level agent, causing Anylogic to encounter a null pointer and throw the error.

I hope that this information is helpful to you.